# Why isn't the frame animation not changing its animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, physics

I've just rendered an animation about a intro, and it seems likes it's on the same thing and it Isn't changing. I'm on frame 21 it just shows the same animation over and over again. Here's is a screenshot of what is repeatably animated.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0deG.png

Comment: Please use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: your end fram is set to 5. so after the first 5 frames you will just be rerendering frame 5.

Comment: A few things. Your frame range (as pointed out by others) is set to render from frame 0 to 5. You would need adjust the end frame to whatever you want the end frame to be. Unfortunately the image posted on the question is not helpful at all to help you any further. Do you have any strips on the VSE and is the Sequencer button enabled? Strips on the VSE would take precedence over the scene. Lastly you don't specify if you are rendering using the Render Animation button or just the render button (Ctrl+F12 or just F12).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers "same animation over and over again", but your end frame is set to "5" in the image, so it would stop there.

Comment: It shows now my end frame is at 608, but it shows the same thong.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the Sequencer in Post Processing options and see if there is no track in the NLA editor that is causing this problem.
[image]